# How to pass a really long string from one script to another in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two python script `sender.py` and `reciever.py`.

I'm trying to send a really long string from sender to receiver by giving it at command line in **`os.system()`** but it gives weird errors on Ubuntu which I can't recall (two line error, each line with **sh**), while on windows it says that **The command line is too long.**

**sender.py** (invoking `os.system()` at the end)

```
class Bob(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.generateReport())
    def generateReport(self):
       # variables used to format report are defined here.
        report = '''some really really long string'''.format(fw_date, release_version, release_date, release_file_tag, crc, checksum[0], checksum[1],
                           checksum[2], checksum[3], checksum[4], checksum[5], pon_firmware, mib_release
                           )
        os.system('python reciever.py '+report)            
        return report


def main():
    try:
        bObj = Bob()
        # miniSVNObj.execute()
    except Exception as ex:
        # print ""
        print(ex)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**reciever.py**

```
import sys
message = "Dear All Concerned, \n"+sys.argv[1]

print(message)
```

Comment: Mabye save it into a file?

Comment: Is there any reason for setting it up this way? Why not have `receiver.py` use `from sender import report`, or save to a file?

Comment: I thought of that but that's not what I'm willing to do until necessary.

Comment: well, given that your approach does not work, you maybe should consider it necessary. You could use pickels: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: @asongtoruin Please take a look at the question again. Is it possible to import this way? I'm sorry I didn't explain the question properly last time.

Comment: @jojo I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: @AnandTyagi what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @asongtoruin I'm trying to pass this report to receiver when the object is created. from the receiver, I want to mail it to different people. This generateReport is just one of the method of my class in which I'm generating report. I don't think I should paste the whole 1000 line code here

Comment: @jojo Your suggestion worked well for me. Thanks.

Comment: @jojo Consider adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the command line is restricted by the operating system. Arbitrarily large pieces of data should be read via a file, either standard input or a file that is explicitly opened.

For example,

```
import subprocess

class Bob(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.generateReport())
    def generateReport(self):
       # variables used to format report are defined here.
        report = '''...'''.format(fw_date, release_version, release_date, release_file_tag, crc, checksum[0], checksum[1],
                           checksum[2], checksum[3], checksum[4], checksum[5], pon_firmware, mib_release
                           )

        with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fh:
            fh.write(report)
            fh.seek(0)
            subprocess.call(['python', 'receiver.py', stdin=fh)
        return report


def main():
    try:
        bObj = Bob()
        # miniSVNObj.execute()
    except Exception as ex:
        # print ""
        print(ex)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And `receiver.py` becomes

```
import sys
msg = sys.stdin.read()
message = "Dear All Concerned, \n" + msg

print(message)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful, but I'm doing it with Pickle. Don't you think that's a better(or faster) way to do it?

Comment: No. Pickling is about turning arbitrary Python objects into strings; it is completely independent of passing the resulting string to another process.

Comment: What I'm doing is dumping the string of report before calling another script. The another script would read from the same pkl file when invoked! It seems to be a better way, I haven't done any speed comparison yet though!

Answer (score 0):

Receiver could get the string via its stdin. That's what it's for :-)

Comment: No, I'd like to pass the report variable only. Please read the question again, I've edited it.

Comment: Expecting a script to take arbitrary amounts of data via the command line is ridiculous. Read from standard input or a file.